# Opencart Fancybox Images

Tags: jquery, opencart

The page currently uses the 'Information' template.
http://goo.gl/RHFza

I tried to add: `class="fancybox"` and `rel="fancybox"` on the link of the image ('Event Image')

but the image doesn't open on fancy box unlike on the product pages, when you click on the product images it opens on fancybox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize your fancybox on the information page.

In the product pages, it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('.fancybox').fancybox({cyclic: true});
//--></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! finally got an answer, just in time